# Do i need sound card to send sound over displayport or HDMI?

Tags: audio, hdmi, sound-card, displayport

I'm planning to buy a motherboard without audio output. Will my monitor play sound with its speakers if I connect the GPU and the monitor with HDMI or DisplayPort cable? I'm planning to use a GTX 960.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need a soundcard. You would see the Monitor as an Audio Playback Device if it supports audio over HDMI. The GTX 960 should be able to handle this with ease.

Comment: Additional note: The intended OS isn't mentioned in the question but is relevant. Windows 10 comes with Nvidia drivers by default that usually work for the intended purpose but sometimes users need to install newer version from Nvidia. OTOH, proprietary drivers aren't included by default in many Linux distros, particularly Debian/Ubuntu and flavors and need to be installed by the user. Audio over HDMI usually don't work with the default open-source driver.